Got error : MongooseError: Operation `users.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms at Timeout.<anonymous>
I am using Mongo DB cloud and trying to insert a document after creating a model in MongoDB.
this is my code to connect to mongo db:
MONGODB_URI=mongodb+srv://user_name:my_password@to-do-list-cluster.a0tgr.mongodb.net
   try {

    const connectionInstance = await mongoose.connect(`${process.env.MONGODB_URI}/taskify`);

    console.log('DB Host : ',connectionInstance.connection.host);

    } catch (error) {

    }

I am successfully connected to MongoDb and got host value.But When I try to insert a document after this, I am getting  MongooseError: Operation users.insertOne() buffering timed out after 10000ms.
This is code for inserting a document:
const User = mongoose.model('User',userSchema);
let newUser = new User({
    userName:'rakeshreddy1542',
    email:'rakeshb@gmail.com',
    password:'Demo@123',
    createdAt:new Date(),
    isLogggedIn:false
});
newUser.save().then(response => {console.log(response)}).catch(err => {console.log(err);});

I have tried all of these:

Changing DNS to 8.8.8.8
Whitelist my IP (added 0.0.0.0 in IP list in Network acccess)
Reinstalled mongoose
used conection string compatible for node version 2 or later

I need a solution to  perform CRUD operations with my mongo db

See if this mongodb forum post answer your question.
